# Test if element i presents before element o

Tags: python

I have 3 lists: `receiveList`, `shipList`, and `sequence`. How to check if elements in `sequence` which belong to `receiveList` have to appear before elements which belong to `shipList`?

Input:

```
receiveList=[1,2,3]
shipList=[4,5,6]
sequence=[3,1,6,2,4,5]
```

Logic: all elements in receiveList have to appear before any of shipList

Output:

```
raise('infeasible solution') #because element 2 in sequence stands behind element 6
```

Comment: Do you mean that all `shipList` should happen before any `receiveList`? Pleasec clarify the logic and provide other examples

Comment: this is a trivial problem that looks like homework rather than a real world one. Could you include your own attempts to write the code for it? Its not useful to just be given an answer without first trying I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sets for efficient tracking of membership and a simple loop with a flag. Once you've seen a "ship" item, do not allow any "receive":

```
r = set(receiveList)
s = set(shipList)

seen_ship = False
for item in sequence:
    if item in s:
        seen_ship = True
    if item in r and seen_ship:
        raise Exception(f'infeasible solution: due to {item}')
```

Output:

```
Exception: infeasible solution: due to 2
```

Comment: Great solution if casting to a set does not cause a problem with say multiple "2" items.

Comment: @JonSG yes not everything is fully clear, in this case one could use a `Counter` and decrement the counts. But OP should clarify and give clear examples in this case

Comment: Ya, I agree and with what is provided this works perfectly and I upvoted it already :-)

Answer (score 0):

As a first step you might want to convert `sequence` into a representation that indicates whether each item is `ship` or `receive`:

```
>>> receiveList=[1,2,3]
>>> shipList=[4,5,6]
>>> sequence=[3,1,6,2,4,5]
>>> action_sequence = ["R" if i in receiveList else "S" if i in shipList else None for i in sequence]
>>> action_sequence
['R', 'R', 'S', 'R', 'S', 'S']
```

Since `R` comes before `S` in the alphabet, a list in which all the `R` entries come before all the `S` entries will be in alphabetically sorted order, so assuming there are no `None` entries, the solution is then simply "is this list already sorted?"

```
>>> action_sequence == sorted(action_sequence)
False
```

Note that this simple check will automatically raise an exception if there are entries in `sequence` that are part of neither list, since those will translate into `None` values in `action_sequence` and `sorted` can't sort `None` vs `str` values.  Your example doesn't specify how exactly you'd want to handle that situation, or if it's something that's possible.  If you want to simply ignore "unknown" values, it'd be easy to filter them out:

```
action_sequence = [a for a in action_sequence if a is not None]
```